# A fast alternative for the below code

Tags: r

I have to compute a matrix.I have written the following code

```
unq_x <- c(102,10226,1026,1024)

unq_x <- as.data.frame(unq_x)

mat1 <- matrix(nrow=nrow(unq_x),ncol=nrow(unq_x))

dim(mat1)



x_distance <- function(i,j)

{
  x1 =unq_x[i,]

 x2 = unq_x[j,]


  dist <- 1 - (x1-x2)/x2
  return(dist)
}

for (i in 1:nrow(unq_x))
{
  for (j in 1:nrow(unq_x))
  {
    mat1[i,j]=x_distance(i,j) 
  }
}
```

This is working fine. But my unq_x has some 10000 numbers which increases the code run time.What other alternatives I can use instead of for loop to fasten up the code

Comment: Your function `function(x, y) 1 - (x - y) / y` is inherently "vectorised", so, you could look/search for `?outer`.

Comment: What have **you tried?**

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for `outer`

```
x <- c(102,10226,1026,1024)
mat2 <- outer(x,x,FUN=function(x,y) 1-(x-y)/y)

> all(mat1 == mat2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: you could shorten 1 - (x-y) / y   into    2 - x/y, right?

Comment: @Rick Yes, and write `2-outer(x,x,"/")`

Answer (score 0):

This applies the function in a vectorised manner across every element of `unq_x`.  The `t` just makes it identical to your original answer.

```
unq_x <- c(102,10226,1026,1024)
mat2 = t(sapply(unq_x, function(x, y) { 1 - (x - y)/y }), y = unq_x)

> all(mat1 == mat2)
[1] TRUE
```

Not exactly a foolproof benchmark, but I stopped the loop as it was taking forever to run.

```
x <- c(runif(min = 1, max =1000, n = 10000))
ptm = proc.time()
m = t(sapply(x, function(x, y) { 1 - (x - y)/y }, y = x))
proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
  7.347   1.528  36.006
```

Though A. Webb's comment is clearly the superior answer.

```
ptm = proc.time()
m = 2 - outer(x, x, `/`)
proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
  0.826   0.813   4.276
```

Comment: Would tapply be faster than for?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Can be arranged as matrix arithmetic
x <- c(102,10226,1026,1024)
mat1 <- -x %*% t(1/x) +2
```